# Dropzone file upload use unique name

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-file-upload, dropzone.js

I am using [dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) for file upload. I just love it. But one thing I want that, I want to use the unique name for each file. So that there will be no repeat file names in the dropzone. So any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks.
Any one there for help?

Answer (score 4):

I think its a better way to use `timestamps` with filenames for uniqueness.

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeForm = {
    paramName: "file",
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 1,
    //[more configuration]

    init: function() {
      var myDropzone = this;

    //[some code]

    this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
        var name = new Date().getTime();//or any other name you want to append with the filename
        formData.append(name, file);
    });
    //[some more code]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its  paramName  Option that you need to use.